# Proving the Set of Computable Functions exists

Tags: logic, set-theory, computer-science

Before I start - I want to say sorry if this has been asked before, I have searched about for a question like this, but haven't been able to find what I am looking for.

To begin, there are a number of (only slightly) different definitions of what a computable function is, so for completeness the definition I am going to be using is:

- A computable function is a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, such that there exists an effective procedure $p$ where for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ - if $p$ is given $n$ as input, then $p$ outputs $f(n)$.

I am only just starting to learn about computability as a hobby, so I am unsure if my definition of a computable function even makes sense (if not, please tell me why it doesn't work). Although I am not sure exactly how an effective procedure rigorously works, I understand the intuitive idea of what one does.

Moving on, if $g$ is any computable function then clearly $g \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and so I feel I should be able to construct the set of computable functions using *the power set axiom* and *the axiom scheme of separation* as $C = \{x \in P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) : ``x$ is a computable function$" \}$. But my question is how exactly do I formulate $``x$ is a computable function$"$ as a logical formula? In other words, how do I show that $ZF \models \exists C$?

(As an extra question, I have been wondering if there is a nice way to make the notion of an *effective procedure* and the process of *giving an output for a given input* more rigorous - in the sense of defining them in terms of mathematical logic? I assume these two questions are linked, which is why I ask.)

Thank you in advance, and sorry if I sound like a dumbass - I'm new to computation.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on what was called {recursion theory]("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory) when I first learnt about it, but is often called computability theory these days. In a nutshell, you need some kind of model for carrying out computations, e.g., Turing machines or $\lambda$-calculus and then your $C$ is the set of all functions whose computations is supported by your model.

Comment: "Effectively computable" is, as you say, a non-rigorous term. There are different definitions of what is computable, but the "Church thesis," which is not a theorem, says that these definitions cover all things we would consider "effectively computable." (We can prove that all our definitions, whether via Turing machines or Markov processes or lambda calculus, are all equivalent, but this doesn't really prove the Church thesis.)

Answer (score 2):

Once you formulated the notion of being a computable function in the language of set theory, the set of *all* computable functions automatically exists, by the very fact that $\sf ZF$ proves that the set of all partial functions $f\colon\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ exists, and therefore by Separation the set of computable functions exist.

Now, to formulate "$f$ is a computable function" in $\sf ZF$ you need to understand that you first need to formalize arithmetic, and then choose one of the many paths you can choose for defining "computable". This is a tedious task, which can be circumvented if one understand the basic principle of foundations of mathematics using set theory: If we can write in, we can write it in the language of set theory.

You need to break down the definition of a "computable function", and then show that each step along the way can be translated into $\{\in\}$, which means that the entire thing can also be translated.

Comment: Thank you as Asaf for such a quick and helpful answer, I actually had no idea that the meaning of "computable" was dependent on anything - does that mean that there are different types of computability and thus you can have certain functions satisfying some computability types, but not others?

Comment: No, I meant to say that there are many *equivalent* ways of defining "computable", and your formalization would depend on which way you choose to define the notion. Just like stating the axiom of choice can be done in so many different ways.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking a lot, but is there any chance you could give me a concrete example of "formalising arithmetic"? Or a source that would be able to list some? Just so I can get my head around the concept.

Comment: It means you need to formalize what is first-order logic, what is a language, terms, formulas, interpretations, satisfaction relation, and so on. Then you need to find a set which can be used to interpret arithmetic, i.e. the natural numbers. Luckily for us, that last part is relatively easy, since $\omega$ along with cardinal/ordinal arithmetic can be used here, and these are relatively "simple". But this is all just a lot of work to properly translate into the language of set theory. It's easier to just understand the process, and that is also not entirely easy (albeit very straightforward).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: you don't need to formalize first-order logic or first-order arithmetic  to define the set of recursive functions. E.g., you can use Turing computability or form the smallest set of functions in $\bigcup_n(\Bbb{N}^n \to \Bbb{N})$  that is closed under the usual constructions of new recursive functions from old.

Comment: The theory of [$\mu$-recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function) is probably the quickest and most direct route to formally showing the "computable functions" are a subset of $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.